# Как указать путь к файлу? Непонятное поведение программы

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, opencv

Есть проект в VS 2012, который работает с библиотекой OpenCV.
В коде пишу полный путь к файлу. Все работает и файл открывается программой.
Отключаю библиотеку(просто меняю название папки, в которой она находится) и добавляю нужные dll в папку с экзешником. Программа запускается, но файл она не открывает. 
Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы. Экзешник требовал 3 dll для запуска, но этих dll не хватало, чтобы открыть файл. Поэтому при доступе к библиотеке программа имела доступ ко всем dll и могла открыть файл, а когда доступ к библиотеке не имела и пользовалась только 3 dll рядом с ней в папке, то открытие файла не работало.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего вы запускаете используя саму студию, по умолчанию у нее working directory находится там же где файл проекта. Соответствено нужно подложить рядом с файлом проекта, либо указать нормальный working directory, либо запускать сам *.exe файл не из студии.

Comment: Я пробовал запускать и из студии и просто экзешник. Все я это проверил. Куда я бы файлы не клал, все равно не работает. Какая-та магия.